# Why I am lossing memory if I work hard?

Tags: brain, neurology

I am a software engineer and you know that it requires to think in logical way to develop code. I am also hard working to reach the dead lines just to do not loss job. But from last 6 months forgetting lot of things in my daily life, I am not able to remember atleast what I did in the morning. Will it be common to have such memory loss or else will it cause permanent loss? I am not able to avoid my thoughts about work as I need to finish work by deadlines. Is there a way to avoid such memory loss?

Comment: Please see a doctor. This is a potential serious issue and we can’t diagnose you over the Internet

Comment: Is there chances that lot of thinking will cause damage to brain?

Comment: No. But nonetheless, you must see a doctor because the symptoms are severe if they kept reoccurring for the past 6 months

Comment: sure thanks for the suggesion, I will try to meet neurologists...

Comment: @user2225190 There are many possible causes, so just see a regular GP first.

Comment: I think a question about how to enhance one's memory function might work.  I'd suggest just deleting this question and starting fresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep deprivation and stress alone can cause this, but it's not the only possible cause... depression and/or anxiety also are correlated (and not unlikely given the length of exposure to chronic stress you mention)... so do see a doctor.

On the [effects of sleep deprivation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2656292/):

> First and foremost, total SD impairs attention and working memory, but it also affects other functions, such as long-term memory and decision-making

["Burnout"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5410591/) while not accepted in the psychiatric bible (DSM) is also a resonable explanation, and can have the same effect(s):

> A systematic review provided by Deligkaris et al. (2014) distinctly showed that burnout is associated with a decline in three main cognitive functions: executive functions, attention and memory (assessed objectively using psychometric tests instead of self-reports).

[Also](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4459038/)

> While burnout does not appear in the 5th edition of the Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders [(DSM-5)], it has been established as a legitimate justification for sick leave in several countries, for instance Sweden.

I hope you live there.

Also, I suggest you read [Mayo clinic's advice](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/alzheimers-disease/in-depth/memory-loss/art-20046326?pg=2) for possible other causes and on dealing with memory loss. The causes I mentioned above are reversible, the neurological ones are less so.

---

And if you think I'm prioritizing the above wrong, [NHS has this](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/memory-loss/)

> Common causes of memory loss
>
> GPs often find that people who see them about memory loss are most likely to have:
>
> - anxiety
> - stress
> - depression
>
> Their memory loss is a result of poor concentration and not noticing things in the first place because of a lack of interest. Sleeping problems often make the memory loss worse.
>
> [...]
>
> Other common causes of memory loss are:
>
> - a head injury – for example, after a car accident
> - a stroke – this cuts off some of the blood supply to the brain and causes brain tissue to die

followed by a longer/separate list of less common causes.

Comment: There are so many different possibilities for causes, that really the only answer should be „go see a doctor“, and that’s not worth as an answer, just comment and vote for closure...

Comment: @Narusan-sedated: i "commented" on the only other symptoms presented. Sure, if you think the other possibilities take precedence, contribute your own answer.

Comment: [This answer explains better than I can in 600 chars why we shouldn’t answer questions that ask for personal medical advice.](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212)

Comment: @Narusan-sedated: [indeed](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/14207/sanity-checking-airplane-advice-re-dvt-walk-every-hour-2-3-hours-ok-to-sleep)

Comment: This current question is requesting personal diagnosis (and has 4 close votes), while the other question is asking about the effectiveness of GCS (and has 0 close votes).

Comment: @Narusan-sedated: the other question is asking for a second opinion after seeing a doctor (on prevention, not diagnosis, it's true) Essentially it's still: "is my doctor right?"

Comment: Well, and this is the difference: *Are there studies to support my doctors opinion* is on-topic here, While *What can cause memory loss* is certainly off-topic. If you do disagree, I’d invite you to start a discussion on [meta], because the comment thread here is not the place.

Comment: Righto, that's why Mayo (see in answer), [NIH](https://www.nia.nih.gov/health/do-memory-problems-always-mean-alzheimers-disease), [Webmd](https://www.webmd.com/brain/forgetfulness-not-always-what-you-think) and so forth have such pages addressed to the general public. These pages don't just say: "Memory problem? Go see a doctor."